# Html cant remove top and bottom spacing between two cells

Tags: html, html-table, spacing

I'm wondering how to remove space between the texts **Experience: 4-5 Years** in [this link](http://beta.fugensoftware.com/inspireworldhr/registration/saniya-khan-saniyainspireworldhr-com/)

There's no padding or margin added. But still i'm getting space on top and bottom. Anybody knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are blue buttons `a.sf-button` in the last `<td>`s. They are `30px` high and have `margin: 0 20px 20px 0` which makes them `50px` high in total. Since this is a `<table>`, the buttons spread all the `<td>`s to the `50px` height.

Answer (score 0):

for the blue image backgound, `a.sf-button` , you have set `margin:0px 20px 20px 0px` and `padding: 6px 12px;` which is causing the trouble...my suggestion is to use `display:table` type for such layouts!! :)